# what is the script that is needed to move a 2D sprite(square)?

Tags: unity, 2d, sprites, movement

I am trying to find a script for my square sprite to move so the player can use WD to move but every time the script won't run. That script is one of many that won't work. This is what I have so far:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

//The abstract keyword enables you to create classes and class members that are incomplete and must be implemented in a derived class.
public abstract class MovingObject : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float moveTime = 0.1f;           //Time it will take object to move, in seconds.
    public LayerMask blockingLayer;         //Layer on which collision will be checked.


    private BoxCollider2D boxCollider;      //The BoxCollider2D component attached to this object.
    private Rigidbody2D rb2D;               //The Rigidbody2D component attached to this object.
    private float inverseMoveTime;          //Used to make movement more efficient.


    //Protected, virtual functions can be overridden by inheriting classes.
    protected virtual void Start()
    {
        //Get a component reference to this object's BoxCollider2D
        boxCollider = GetComponent<BoxCollider2D>();

        //Get a component reference to this object's Rigidbody2D
        rb2D = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();

        //By storing the reciprocal of the move time we can use it by multiplying instead of dividing, this is more efficient.
        inverseMoveTime = 1f / moveTime;
    }


    //Move returns true if it is able to move and false if not. 
    //Move takes parameters for x direction, y direction and a RaycastHit2D to check collision.
    protected bool Move(int xDir, int yDir, out RaycastHit2D hit)
    {
        //Store start position to move from, based on objects current transform position.
        Vector2 start = transform.position;

        // Calculate end position based on the direction parameters passed in when calling Move.
        Vector2 end = start + new Vector2(xDir, yDir);

        //Disable the boxCollider so that linecast doesn't hit this object's own collider.
        boxCollider.enabled = false;

        //Cast a line from start point to end point checking collision on blockingLayer.
        hit = Physics2D.Linecast(start, end, blockingLayer);

        //Re-enable boxCollider after linecast
        boxCollider.enabled = true;

        //Check if anything was hit
        if (hit.transform == null)
        {
            //If nothing was hit, start SmoothMovement co-routine passing in the Vector2 end as destination
            StartCoroutine(SmoothMovement(end));

            //Return true to say that Move was successful
            return true;
        }

        //If something was hit, return false, Move was unsuccesful.
        return false;
    }


    //Co-routine for moving units from one space to next, takes a parameter end to specify where to move to.
    protected IEnumerator SmoothMovement(Vector3 end)
    {
        //Calculate the remaining distance to move based on the square magnitude of the difference between current position and end parameter. 
        //Square magnitude is used instead of magnitude because it's computationally cheaper.
        float sqrRemainingDistance = (transform.position - end).sqrMagnitude;

        //While that distance is greater than a very small amount (Epsilon, almost zero):
        while (sqrRemainingDistance > float.Epsilon)
        {
            //Find a new position proportionally closer to the end, based on the moveTime
            Vector3 newPostion = Vector3.MoveTowards(rb2D.position, end, inverseMoveTime * Time.deltaTime);

            //Call MovePosition on attached Rigidbody2D and move it to the calculated position.
            rb2D.MovePosition(newPostion);

            //Recalculate the remaining distance after moving.
            sqrRemainingDistance = (transform.position - end).sqrMagnitude;

            //Return and loop until sqrRemainingDistance is close enough to zero to end the function
            yield return null;
        }
    }


    //The virtual keyword means AttemptMove can be overridden by inheriting classes using the override keyword.
    //AttemptMove takes a generic parameter T to specify the type of component we expect our unit to interact with if blocked (Player for Enemies, Wall for Player).
    protected virtual void AttemptMove<T>(int xDir, int yDir)
        where T : Component
    {
        //Hit will store whatever our linecast hits when Move is called.
        RaycastHit2D hit;

        //Set canMove to true if Move was successful, false if failed.
        bool canMove = Move(xDir, yDir, out hit);

        //Check if nothing was hit by linecast
        if (hit.transform == null)
            //If nothing was hit, return and don't execute further code.
            return;

        //Get a component reference to the component of type T attached to the object that was hit
        T hitComponent = hit.transform.GetComponent<T>();

        //If canMove is false and hitComponent is not equal to null, meaning MovingObject is blocked and has hit something it can interact with.
        if (!canMove && hitComponent != null)

            //Call the OnCantMove function and pass it hitComponent as a parameter.
            OnCantMove(hitComponent);
    }


    //The abstract modifier indicates that the thing being modified has a missing or incomplete implementation.
    //OnCantMove will be overriden by functions in the inheriting classes.
    protected abstract void OnCantMove<T>(T component)
        where T : Component;
}
```

Comment: Abstract classes can't be instantiated directly. If you try to attach this class to a gameobject, you'll get errors and the script will fail to run. Either remove the abstraction, or create a class that implements MovingObject.

Comment: Scripts are not like plugins/extensions, they are written  for extremely specific needs/problems.  If you ask two persons to write identically looking  versions of tic-tac-toe, the scripts between the two (identical) versions will be different and incompatible. If you hope to achieve anything remotely working you (or someone in your team) really need first to understand at least super basic coding/algorithms  (C# for Unity). The reality is that there is no way around it.

Comment: The best thing that you can do is to put aside Unity/gamedev for 1-3 months and concentrate on coding exclusively (again, C# for Unity). You will thank yourself countless times for that. As you already saw, otherwise you have not hard but impossible road ahead. The next script that you will need, and the one after it will be even more complex and specific to your personal needs.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the other comments, there a million ways to make this happen. The snippet attached includes a lot of bit that you don't really address in your question. So I'll assume that you are, at the moment, only concerned about making the square move. The easiest way I can think off to do this is something like this:

```
 void Update(){
    Vector3 forward = new Vector3(1,0,0); //assumes increasing the x position moves forward
    float i = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * speed * Time.deltaTime; //assumes there's some global float called speed
    transform.Translate(forward * i, Space.World)
}
```

This assumes some global float called "speed" in the class to control the rate of movement. Here's a couple links that might be helpful:

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.Translate.html
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetAxis.html

I'd suggest getting the moving part to work, then work on handling collisions, if I were offering advice. ;)

*I didn't run this code in unity to test it. But I'm pretty confident I didn't make any breaking errors.

Thanks!

Comment: That "forward" vector is already available as the static member Vector3.right, if you'd like to skip defining your own. ;)

Comment: True, I generally define those Vector3's because I think it reads clearer. But you are correct.